# Change format of column using formula

Tags: regex, google-sheets-formula, re2

I have a column of 'phone numbers in my Google Sheets, e.g.:

```
3100000000
03100000000
923100000000
+923100000000
00923100000000
```

and want to convert all of them in same format like so:

```
923100000000
```

Comment: How to format `3100000000` into `923100000000`? The number of digits is 10 vs 12.

Comment: need to add prefix `92` before `3100000000`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex). As a **sample**,

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(A1),"92\d{10}$"),REGEXEXTRACT("92"&A1,"92\d{10}$"))
```

- \d{10} 10 digits
- $ end of string
- IFERROR to add "92",If it is not present.